# Elasticsearch Query DSL date range problems

Tags: elasticsearch

I want all records for the last 24 hours. If I use date math (now) I don't get any records. If I manually specify a date I get records but some are from several days ago.

Example record:

```
"_index": "platform-862a:logs-001386",
"_type": "doc",
"_id": "Ihg0enMBqxITPs13KML0",
"_score": 20.144087,
"_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2020-07-23T05:45:04.893Z",
    "timeMillis": 1595819172661,
    "application": "an app name",
    "message": "an error message"
}
```

**Edit:** Added `timeMillis` field to the example above. Turns out to be the key to the answer.

Query:

```
{
  "_source": [
    "@timestamp",
    "timeMillis",
    "application",
    "message"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",
              "gte": "2020-07-26T00:00:00Z"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "level": "ERROR"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "environment": "prod"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "application": "app1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "application": "app12"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

i'm sending the query via Postman. i'm in CDT, logs were written by a server in UTC. i thought that might be the issue but i'm seeing records from 2020-07-23, several days ago.

if i change the range to:

```
"@timestamp": {
  "gte": "now-2d"
}
```

I get no records (hits.total=0).

I've tried with and without specifying time zone, date format, a lt date, inside a filter block, etc. but nothing gets me just the last 24 hours. I've tried without the `should` block and removing all the other `must` blocks.

And the format i'd like, `now-1d`, returns nothing at all.

Comment: Can you share the mapping for your index?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what that means. I'm new to elasticsearch and the logging/Kibana infrastructure is owned by the company infrastructure team.

Comment: Can you update your question with the result you get from running `GET platform-862a:logs-001386` ?

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had the query syntax wrong but it looks like the problem was specific to my company/instance.

The query works if i switch from `@timestamp` (which is a valid value in my schema) to `timeMillis` (a long value). The revised query is below.

I'm not sure if this answer will help other people. As Val noted in the question comments, it helps to look at your index mapping. I can't look at mine (company permissions block us). I don't know why it didn't work with `@timestamp` since that's a valid field and looks like a date (I'm not sure how it's mapped because i can't see the index schema) but I know the date math functions work with the date-as-a-long field.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timeMillis": {
              "gte": "now-1d"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "level": "ERROR"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "environment": "prod"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "application": "app1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "application": "app12"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```